# incompatible shapes of labels

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

```
features = df.iloc[:, :-1]
labels = df.iloc[:, -1]
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, 
test_size=0.33, random_state=42, stratify=labels)
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, dtype='int64')
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, dtype='int64')
# OR
numerical_features = features.select_dtypes(include=['int64'])
numerical_columns = numerical_features.column
ct = ColumnTransformer([('numeric', Normalizer(), numerical_columns)], 
                       remainder='passthrough')
X_train = ct.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = ct.transform(X_test)
le = LabelEncoder()
Y_train = le.fit_transform(Y_train.astype('int64'))
Y_test = le.transform(Y_test.astype('int64'))
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes=7, dtype='int64')
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes=7, dtype='int64')
# I have no clue which way is correct
model = Sequential(name='forest')
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
ls_optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=ls_optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', 
              metrics=[CategoricalAccuracy(name='accuracy'),  
              F1Score(average='weighted', name='f1_score'),
              AUC(name='auc'), Precision(name='precision'),
              Recall(name='recall')])
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=16, verbose=1)
loss, accuracy, f1_score, auc, precision, recall = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
```

The above code throws this error:

```
12 history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=16, verbose=1)
    ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int64: <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, 8) dtype=int64>
IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 7
ValueError: Shapes (None, 8) and (None, 7) are incompatible
```

I tried a lot of things with converting labels to one-hot encoded arrays with the correct data type. I would appreciate if someone could explain the issue.

Comment: Would you post some sample data to run through your code? It would help to identify what's going on.

Comment: @Jesse Sealand  if I understand you, I have 55 columns, the last = 'class'(it's labels) I tried to predict. Also 7 classes, The covertypes. df.head():
Elevation Aspect Slope Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology Vertical_Distance_To_Hydrology Horizontal_Distance_To_Roadways Hillshade_9am Hillshade_Noon Hillshade_3pm Horizontal_Distance_To_Fire_Points ... Soil_Type32 Soil_Type33 Soil_Type34 Soil_Type35 Soil_Type36 Soil_Type37 Soil_Type38 Soil_Type39 Soil_Type40 class
0 2596 51 3 258 0 510 221 232 148 6279 ... 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 5///1 2590 56 2 212 -6 390 220 235 151 6225 ... 
5 rows × 55 columns

Comment: or you need just like this: data = 'Elevation': [2596, 2590, 2804, 2785, 2595, 2637, 2857], 'Horizontal_Distance_To_Hydrology': [258, 212, 345, 268, 242, 175, 153], 'Soil_Type33': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'label': ['5', '2', '3', '4', '1', '4', 2'] df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Likely two problems in the code:

```py
# In these lines, dtype='int64' should probably be dtype='float32' otherwise it's tricky to compute the loss
# Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes=7, dtype='int64')
# Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes=7, dtype='int64')
Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes=7, dtype='float32')
Y_test = to_categorical(Y_test, num_classes=7, dtype='float32')
```

```py
# If there are indeed 7 classes (see Y_train and Y_test), here it should be 7, not 8
# model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
```

Comment: He's right. The final layer in your model has to be a 1 to 1 match to the shape of the your labels. It's one of those things once you see it it's obvious and you can't believe you missed it.  It's easy to get lost in your own code sometimes.

Comment: actually, I've tried a lot those attempts before. Here what we have after corrects: Y_train = to_categorical(Y_train, num_classes=7, dtype='float32')(red underline)
IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 7
(---> 74   categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1)
Still remain the same. The question is, if I have the right size of classes, where this index come from? Look, if I remain the num_classes=7 from Y_train/Y_test, it  allows me to move on, but after the model compile, when we coming to model.fit we have this:ValueError: Shapes (None, 8) and (None, 7) are incompatible

Comment: Thank you guys, for your attention. Look what we have: I remove the num_classes=7 from Y_train/Y_test, it allows me to move on, and I left 8 classes in the output layer. There we go: Epoch 1/100
24330/24330 [==============================] - 76s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5458 - accuracy: 0.7653 - f1_score: 0.7595 - auc: 0.9758 - precision: 0.7776 - recall: 0.7480
It works, but anyway we have questions)))

Comment: Glad you found a way out :) It's possible that you have actually 8 classes in the dataset.